# Insert Multiple Column based on existing table aggregated

Tags: sql-server

I currently have a SQL query that will go through a table, get the distinct dates and then insert the results into another table.

```
INSERT [fd_movements_dates](Date)
SELECT DISTINCT(CONVERT(date, MsgTimestamp)) as Date
FROM [fd_movements]
ORDER BY Date
```

I'm wanting to expand it so that it sums the amount of records within each day. The MsgTimestamp column is a datetime2(0).

**Expected result**

01-01-2020 - 345600

02-01-2020 - 654000

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT [fd_movements_dates](Date, Cnt)
SELECT (CONVERT(date, MsgTimestamp)) as Date
    ,COUNT(1) AS Cnt
FROM [fd_movements]
GROUP BY (CONVERT(date, MsgTimestamp))
```